# Docker fails when running command at exactly same time

Tags: docker

My current setup is a Aws EB docker instance in which I have a php-cli container running. I execute jobs with cron, some at the same time, and it is there it fails without any messages.

eg

```bash
* * * * * docker exec php-cli php bin/console myCommand1 >> /tmp/log1.log 2>&1
* * * * * docker exec php-cli php bin/console myCommand2 >> /tmp/log2.log 2>&1
```

One will work and the other will not. Both commands work if run by itself.

I have googled around without finding any similar issues.

Comment: What do the commands do? How about piping their output to a log?

Comment: They are doing the same thing, just printing some text for testing purpose. If I running them after each other it works. It's something with running docker at the exactly same time.

Comment: How do you know it fail as nothing was redirect from cron?

Comment: Sorry, I log it to a textfile. I have edited and added it to my question.